# /usr/sbin/postconf: No such file or directory in Virtualmin CentOS

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, webmin, virtual-server

I installed SSL using Virtualmin.  It got installed successfully. After installing I am getting the following error.  And I could not see any options under the virtual server please see the attached image.

```
Failed to query Postfix config command to get the current value of parameter virtual_alias_maps: sh: /usr/sbin/postconf: No such file or directory
```

[image]

I am using CentOS 6.2
I dont know how to fix this issue also I dont know why postconf is used for.

Please help me to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed it by reinstalling Virtualmin...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reinstall postfix.

I'm not a CentOS geek, but here's the official HowTo:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

This error can happen on Dabian based distributions as well. Here you just install postfix package, like so:

`$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install postfix`

Comment: Thank you for the answer..  I will try it if I get the problem again.  Hope this answer would help any other so +1

Comment: Please provide the steps to install Postfix also.  Thanks..

Comment: I put in the steps for both CentOS and Debian.